# Text is forcing DIVs to not stay the same size

Tags: html, css, height, equals

Im trying to keep everything equal on my page. When there is too much text in one DIV its pushing the side down. How do I keep both DIVs equal height to the max of their Parent DIV on desktop?

I tried playing around with the table display but that didn't go so well for me, but I'm also not that versed in it.

```css
<style><!--

 
.pageRow {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 white-space: nowrap;
}


.pageBlock {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: top;
 padding-left: 15px; 
 padding-right: 15px;
 white-space: normal;
 
}



.pageText {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 object-fit: contain;
 vertical-align: top;
}


.pageMap {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: bottom;
}



@media (max-width: 768px) {


.pageRow {
    display: inline-block;
 white-space: normal;

}  

.pageBlock {

    display: inline-block;
 width: 75%;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 
}




.pageText {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: middle;
 align-items: center;
 object-fit: contain;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;

    
}


.pageMap {
 display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
}
--></style>
```

```html
<div class="pageRow">
 <div class="pageBlock">
  <div class="pageText">
   <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Title 1</strong></p>
<p><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span></p>
  </div><!--/.pageText-->
  <div class="pageMap">
   <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d55565170.29301636!2d-132.08532758867793!3d31.786060306224!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x54eab584e432360b%3A0x1c3bb99243deb742!2sUnited+States!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1505170144549" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div><!--/.pageMap-->
 </div><!--/.pageBlock-->
 
 <div class="pageBlock">
   <div class="pageText">
    <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Title 2</strong></p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries.</p>
   </div><!--/.pageText-->
   <div class="pageMap">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d55565170.29301636!2d-132.08532758867793!3d31.786060306224!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x54eab584e432360b%3A0x1c3bb99243deb742!2sUnited+States!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1505170144549" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
   </div><!--/.pageMap-->
  </div><!--/.pageBlock-->

</div><!--/.pageRow-->
```

Comment: I'm guessing you want both to be aligned horizontally.

Comment: use max-height. Use !important with it (only) if necessary. set the overflow to auto or scroll or hidden, whichever suits your needs

Comment: You could just use height if you wanted to fix it (with percentage or pixels.) e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/29dc4L3L/

Comment: I have tried all of that (height, max-height) but seems to not be doing anything. I must be missing something I left it out because it seemed to not do anything.

Comment: If you shrink the image a bit and the text starts to wrap around you can see even with height in your fiddle its changing the size of the left DIV

Comment: @MidnightDisco (I only saw your comments now because you didn't tag me with the '@' sign. ) See my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should probably fix the height and width to a max so that the text can't increase the div anymore.

```
    height: 500px; /*or something around that, there isn't any width percentages */
```

Comment: well actually the text on the right DIV actually should be increasing the height because it is wrapping down, I'm trying to see if when that increases it should increase the entire wrapper, which in turn should increase the size of the left DIV since it is at 100%, but the left DIV stays the smaller size instead.

Comment: If it increases the wrapper, it wouldn't increase the left div because it's height isn't being affected, only its position.

Comment: So with my set up of wrapper > block > text and map , when the text gets higher on the right, that would push the block on the right div to get bigger, pushing the wrapper to get bigger. I want the left block to also get bigger, filling the entire height of the wrapper, and then keep the map at the bottom of the block the entire time. that would kind of fix it all.

Answer (score 0):

The height/max-height works but it's appearance will depend on what YOU set the height/max-height to be. Because the height was set in percentage (which was for e.g. to demo that you can use either - fiddle with a jsfiddle!), the height was adjusting to 50% of the height, which was variable. But the text was wrapping because of the max-height being set.

Also, when I initially copied your code to create the fiddle, you had an extra close div tag, look out for that. For the following css to work, put the text in paragraph 2 (in the right div) between span tags. Your current code only has the text between span tags in the left div.

I narrowed your divs to 45% (from 50%) because when the text was wrapping, the scroll bar was unseen unless the user scrolled across.  Try it out in the snippet or the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/29dc4L3L/)

```css
  .pageRow {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.pageBlock {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  white-space: normal;
}

.pageText p span {
  height: 120px;
  max-height: 90px!important;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-y: auto;
```

```html
<div class="pageRow">
  <div class="pageBlock">
    <div class="pageText">
      <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Title 1</strong></p>
      <p><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span></p>
    </div>
    <!--/.pageText-->
    <div class="pageMap">
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d55565170.29301636!2d-132.08532758867793!3d31.786060306224!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x54eab584e432360b%3A0x1c3bb99243deb742!2sUnited+States!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1505170144549"
        width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <!--/.pageMap-->
  </div>
  <!--/.pageBlock-->

  <div class="pageBlock">
    <div class="pageText">
      <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Title 2</strong></p>
      <p><span>      
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries.</span></p>
    </div>
    <!--/.pageText-->
    <div class="pageMap">
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d55565170.29301636!2d-132.08532758867793!3d31.786060306224!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x54eab584e432360b%3A0x1c3bb99243deb742!2sUnited+States!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1505170144549"
        width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <!--/.pageMap-->
  </div>
  <!--/.pageBlock-->

</div>
<!---page Row-->
```